# Is there any common rider for ensuring appliance and water upkeep in an apartment building?

Tags: united-states, residential-lease, michigan

We are about to sign a 12-month upper-income lease with a large apartment building in Michigan.

We have seen some past reviews that worry us about maintenance issues once we move in.   One was even as bad as saying when a pipe burst, they had water leaking into their apartment for over a week.

This is a high-rise building that includes all the appliances, so we'd be reliant on them for maintenance.  Are there any recommendations to ensuring that we'd have proper upkeep and maintenance on our apartment and appliances during the lease?

Comment: Not to be rude, but you probably shouldn't move in if there are serious concerns.

Comment: There's limited availability in the area for what we're looking for and a time crunch.  We did have a good experience on our tour.

Comment: Did you bring the concerns up with them?